# Cocos2D: kazmath/kazmath.h file not found

Tags: file, path, header, cocos2d-iphone

I am upgrading Cocos2D 0.99.5 to version 2. I was hoping the other Stack Overflow questions about this would help me but they have not.

Right now I have the kazmath folder inside my project folder.  It's the kazmath folder inside the include folder.

[image: project folder structure]

I get the errors "kazmath/kazmath.h file not found" and "kazmath/mat4.h file not found"

In my header search paths I've tried various things including "${SRCROOT}/kazmath" recursive and non recursive.

I don't know if it matters, but in my project navigator, the folders look like this:

[image: Project Navigator]

Comment: in build settings the path must expand to the actual location of the kazmath folder, tweak it until it is right using the "${SRCROOT}/libs/kazmath" approach (check the expanded path after you end editing and compare it with finder).

Comment: Yeah it's the same path as shown above in the finder, right?

Comment: normally kazmath is a subfolder of cocos2d. Anyway, since SRCROOT is where the xcodeproj is the path should be just "kazmath" or "${SRCROOT}/kazmath"

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2D was already looking for the folder "kazmath". I stuck the kazmath and cocos2d folders into a libs folder on my project navigator and made the search path "${SRCROOT}/libs"